# Is the 4th bit of a number 1

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bit

Is there a way to make it check the fourth bit for any number, no matter how many bits does the number have

```
a=73

if (a>>3&1==1):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What do you expect?

Comment: @glglgl I have to check if the fourth bit of a number is 1, if its 1 print True

Comment: That's clear from the title. But the fourth bit should be tested with 4, not with 3. Or do you count from 1? Then it is fine.

Comment: @glglgl it seems it counts from right, so the number depends on how much bits there are. But is there a way to make it check the fourth bit for any number, no matter how many bits does it have

Comment: `bin(a)[4] == '1'`

Answer (score 1):

First, a question: What is the fourth bit? Is it bit 4, counted from 0, or is it bit 3?

Probably, you encounter a operator precedence problem. First, let's simplify your code:

```
a = 18

print(a>>3&1==1) # equivalent to your original code
print((a >> 3) & 1 == 1) # closer to your intent
print((a >> 3) & 1) # see what happens
```

But that's indeed a way to test for bit 3 (whose value is 8). 18 = 16 + 2, so it has bit 4 and bit 1 set. That's why you get `False`.

Note that the bits are always counted from right to left.

I would probably do it the other way:

```
print (a & 0x08)
print (a & (1 << 3))
```

WIth your changed question, you have now 73, which is 64 + 8 + 1, which are bits 6, 3 and 0.

Comment: Fourth bit as counted from the human perspective. In 73 it's 1001001, so the fourth bit is 1

Answer (score 0):

More simple:

```
def fourthBit(bin_number):
   i = 0
   while bin_number[i] == 0: i = i+1
   return bin_number[3+i]
```